# Laravel - Why is my test setUp() function failing?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, factory, laravel-9

I've constructed a test in which I'm using this setUp() function

```
public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        Carbon::setTestNow('2001-01-01');
        (new UserFactory())
            ->for(Company::factory()
                ->state(
                    [
                        'name' => 'test company'
                    ]
                )
            )
            ->for(Role::factory()->state([
                'name' => 'admin',
                'id' => 1,
                'hierarchy' => 2
            ]))
            ->createOne();
        $user = User::first();
        $this->actingAs($user);
    }
```

But I'm getting this error: `Error : Class "Database\Factories\CompanyFactory" not found

```
C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64\php.exe C:/Users/papal/projects/cloud/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration C:\Users\papal\projects\cloud\phpunit.xml --filter "/(Tests\\Feature\\Services\\MassiveUploadServicesTest::testGenerateRecipes)( .*)?$/" --test-suffix MassiveUploadServicesTest.php C:\Users\papal\projects\cloud\tests\Feature\Services --teamcity
Testing started at 10:13 ...
PHPUnit 9.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


Error : Class "Database\Factories\CompanyFactory" not found
 C:\Users\papal\projects\cloud\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory.php:821
 C:\Users\papal\projects\cloud\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory.php:16
 C:\Users\papal\projects\cloud\tests\Feature\Services\MassiveUploadServicesTest.php:37
```

you may think that `CompanyFactory.php` does not exists but is does, in `...\database\factories\CompanyFactory.php`

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Company>
 */
class CompanyFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->word
        ];
    }
}
```

**What am I missing**? This began happening from night to day without any changes in the test. I did a rollback but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've recently added or moved the CompanyFactory class or made changes to your project's directory structure, run the following command to regenerate the Composer autoloader:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: It worked thanks! What's a probable cause for this kind of issue? Do you think changes were made to directories? We just did a big rollback. I'm sure the CompanyFactory class didn't move from its folder.

Comment: I don't know exactly, but caching your configs and regenerating the autoload is considered a good reflex in this kind of situation.